# La clase "tabla" de una table creada no toma todas las propiedades de igual forma. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, class, table

cree una tabla con document.createElement("table") y le aplique la class tabla. Cuando voy al ordenador veo que no me toma algunas propiedades como el color y el border-collapse. Alguien entiende porque sucede esto?

Cuando voy al ordenador el "border-color" y el "border-collapse" aparecen tachados, pero otras propiedades no, y no entiendo porque pasa esto.

Gracias

```
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {
            margin-top: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            color: mediumturquoise;
        }

        #divCentral {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            border: solid 1px gray;
            border-radius: 7px;
            margin: 100px auto;
        }

        .tabla{//class que se va a adjuntar a la tabla
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            border-style: solid  ;
            border-color:gray ;
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;

        }


    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var div1 = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
            var tabla = document.createElement("table");//tabla creada
            div1.appendChild(tabla);
            tabla.className="tabla";
         }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Calendario</h1>

    <div id="divCentral">

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Simplemente mueve tu JS al final del HTML justo antes de que cierre la etiqueta body, pues a como lo pones ahorita no encuentra la etiqueta div por que justo cuando lee esa línea el div aún no existe ya que se encuentra mas abajo

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!, pero creo que no es eso, porque me sigue apareciendo tachadas las propiedades. Cuando inspecciono el elemento, la clase tabla aparece normal, pero en el elemento table aparecen tachados

Comment: Tienes que tener algun conflicto con otro CSS, el ejemplo que has puesto funciona bien.

Comment: Hola @Juan. Revisé y encontré que no se "aplicó" el estilo a tu tabla porque no tiene celdas. Al agregárselas podrás visualizar los resultados. Ahora bien, los estilos son aplicados a la la tabla y no a las celdas. Si tengo algo de tiempo, publicaré una respuesta explicando el problema con su posible solución.

Comment: También debes tomar en cuenta que en CSS no se colocan comentarios con `//`. Para agregar comentarios, utilice `/* */` en su lugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Propiedades CSS en la tabla

> **Importante:** se desarrollarán algunos ejemplos para dar un poco de contexto al problema planteado con el código.

La razón por la que no se "aplica" la regla CSS a la tabla es porque no tiene celdas. Por ejemplo, partiendo de los fragmento que siguen más abajo.

#### Tabla sin celdas

**HTML:**

```html
...
<div id="divCentral"></div>
```

Y **JavaScript:**

```js
window.onload = function () {
  ...
  var tabla = document.createElement("table");
  div1.appendChild(tabla);
  tabla.className = "tabla";
};
```

Producirá el siguiente resultado (en el código HTML):

```css
#divCentral {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.tabla {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!-- Resultado en el código HTML -->
<div id="divCentral">
  <table class="tabla"></table>
</div>
```

Por lo tango, no se observan resultados de la regla `.tabla { ... }` sobre la tabla que se creó cuando se insertó en el elemento `<div id="divCentral"></div>` porque la tabla no tiene celdas.

#### Tabla con celdas

Si se modifica el código anterior, es decir, se agregan celdas a la tabla observaremos la aplicación de las propiedades CSS de la regla `.tabla{ ... }` sobre la tabla:

```css
#divCentral {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.tabla {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div id="divCentral">
  <table class="tabla">
    <!-- Celdas que se agregaron a la tabla -->
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Se observan los resultados de la regla **CSS** `.tabla{ ... }` sobre la tabla.

#### Tabla con celdas usando JavaScript

> **Por favor,** lea los comentarios que se ubican dentro del código. En ellos se explican detalles específicos para entender un poco el contexto del problema resuelto.

En esta oportunidad, reproduciremos la solución del problema incorporando **JavaScript:**

```js
onload = () => {
  // A parte de crearse la tabla, se crean los
  // elementos que formarán la celda de la tabla:
  let 
    tabla = document.createElement( "table" ),
    fila = document.createElement( "tr" ),
    celda = document.createElement( "td" );
  
  // Se inserta el elemento «tr» en la tabla:
  tabla.append( fila );
  
  // Y se coloca el elemento «td» en la fila:
  fila.append( celda );
  
  // Se inserta la tabla en el elemento «#divCentral»
  divCentral.appendChild(tabla);
  
  // Y finalmente, le agregamos la clase 
  // «.tabla» al elemento «table»:
  tabla.classList.add( "tabla" );
};
```

```css
/* 
   Los estilos no se modificaron,
   excepto en la eliminación del comentario
   que empezaba con » // en la regla «.tabla{ ... }» y 
   la propiedad «margin-top: 200px;» de la regla h1 { ... }
*/

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: mediumturquoise;
}

#divCentral {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

/* En esta regla CSS se ubicaba un comentario que 
   empezaba con //. Fue eliminado */
.tabla {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<h1>Calendario</h1>
<div id="divCentral"></div>
```

> **Nota:** en esta publicación no se explica cómo escribir código correctamente. El objetivo principal es explicar el problema planteado en la pregunta.

#### Dato adicional

Tomando en cuenta la inquietud de tu pregunta que cito a continación:

> Cuando voy al ordenador el "border-color" y el "border-collapse" aparecen tachados, pero otras propiedades no, y no entiendo porque pasa esto.

Las propiedades que suelen estar tachadas, si están escritas correctamente, porque hay otra regla CSS con el mismo selector de clase (`.tabla`en tu caso) que están usando las mismas propiedades que mencionas. Es decir, las sobreescriben.

Comment: Gracias David! lo habia solucionado eliminando la propiedad Border'collapse, porque no se bien porque, se cancelaba mutuamente con border-style:solid. Pero tu respuesta es mas completa y mejor. Saludos